# Popup over sticky components

Tags: html, css

I have two sticky boxes. On hovering over a particular area inside the sticky boxes a popup opens. **I want these popups to appear always on top of the sticky boxes.** But increasing the z index of one hides the other. Any solution ?

Note - Removing sticky from the boxes and keeping z index of both the box same solves the problem but I need the boxes to be sticky.

```css
.box {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: sticky;
  
}

.innerBox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
}

.popup1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 35px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.popup2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 35px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}

.box1:hover .popup1 {
  display: block;
}

.box2:hover .popup2 {
  display: block;
}

.boxUp {
  z-index: 3;
}

.boxDown {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box boxUp">
    <div class="innerBox box1">
      <p>
      Hover Here
      </p>
      <div class="popup1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box boxDown">
    <div class="innerBox box2">
    <p>
    Hover Here
    </p>
      <div class="popup2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `z-index` on hover the `.box`

```css
.box {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: sticky;
  
}

.innerBox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
}

.popup1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 35px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.popup2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 35px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}

.box1:hover .popup1 {
  display: block;
}

.box2:hover .popup2 {
  display: block;
}

.box:hover {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box boxUp">
    <div class="innerBox box1">
      <p>
      Hover Here
      </p>
      <div class="popup1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box boxDown">
    <div class="innerBox box2">
    <p>
    Hover Here
    </p>
      <div class="popup2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```